# How to disable blur in autocomplete in Xcode 11?

Tags: xcode, catalina, auto-complete

Since Xcode 11.0 autocomplete suggestions have blurry font sometimes:
[image: Xcode Autocomplete]

Don't know whether it's a bug or a feature but my eyes suffer because of it.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug because I'm not seeing this in on my 2015 MBP. Have you tried updating to the latest Xcode version (11.1) to see if it's fixed?

Comment: ik Air's (2017)  screen is bad, but I don't see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMmEq.png on Xcode 10.3 @fsb

Comment: @fsb, no App Store didn't notify me. I'm using 11.0. I'll update and tell you.

Comment: @fsb, the blur remains after update. Sad.